# Realm "Collection is no longer valid" error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a common crash that according to Crashlytics is:

```
Fatal Exception: RLMException
Collection is no longer valid
```

According to Crashlytics the error occurs at

```
RLMSupport.swift line 57
```

What could be the cause of such issue?

Comment: Please share more of your Realm code, along with what you are doing when this error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid Realm Collections or Objects means that either the Realm backing this collection was invalidated explicitly by calling [`RLMRealm.invalidate()`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMRealm(im)invalidate) or if the collection is an `RLMArray` or `RLMLinkingObjects`, if its parent object was deleted from the Realm.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone have the same issue might due to something like this

```
let infoModels: Results<CardGroupDisplayInfoModel> = infoStore.getAll()
infoModels.forEach { model in
    model.assetIds.forEach { id in
        try? stubRealm.safeWrite {
            stubRealm.delete(model)
        }
    }
}
```

this will give you `Collection is no longer valid (RLMException)`

should be doing like this

```
var modelToBeDeleted: [Object] = []
infoModels.forEach { model in
    model.assetIds.forEach { id in
        modelToBeDeleted.append(model)
    }
}

modelToBeDeleted.forEach { model in
    try? stubRealm.safeWrite {
        stubRealm.delete(model)
    }
}
```